# error with setPixels

Tags: android, image-processing

i am trying to edit images. but i am getting errors with setPixels.

```
        picw = pic.getWidth();
        pich = pic.getHeight();
        picsize = picw*pich;        
        int[] pix = new int [picsize];
        pic.getPixels(pix, 0, picw, 0, 0, picw, pich);  
        pic.setPixels(pix,0,pic.getWidth(),0,0,pic.getWidth(),pic.getHeight());
```

but i am getting illegal state exception with setPixels

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.setPixels(Bitmap.java:878)
  at com.sandyapps.testapp.testapp.onCreate(testapp.java:66)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Immutable bitmap crash error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119582/android-immutable-bitmap-crash-error)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I think your `Bitmap` is not mutable (see [setPixel()'s documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setPixel%28int,%20int,%20int%29)).

If so, create a mutable copy of this Bitmap (using `Bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config config, boolean isMutable)` as an example) and work on this one.

Answer (score 9):

It's simple, just use the following command to change it to a mutable Bitmap:

```
myBitmap = myBitmap.copy( Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 , true);
```

Now the Bitmap `myBitmap` is replaced by the same Bitmap but this time is mutable

You can also choose another way of storing Pixels (ARGB_8888 etc..):
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html

Comment: bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true);

Answer (score 5):

Most probably your `pic` is immutable. By default, any bitmap created from drawable would be immutable.

If you need to modify an existing bitmap, you should do following:

```
// Create a bitmap of the same size
Bitmap newBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(pic.getWidth(), pic.getHeight(), Config.ARGB);
// Create a canvas  for new bitmap
Canvas c = new Canvas(newBmp); 

// Draw your old bitmap on it. 
c.drawBitmap(pic, 0, 0, new Paint());
```

Comment: `Config.ARGB_8888` might be required. `Config.ARGB` was giving me a 'cannot resolve symbol' error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Use to fix it:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inMutable = true;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.my_bitmap, opt );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem and finally fixed after long time.

```
public static void filterApply(Filter filter){
    Bitmap bitmcopy = PhotoModel.getInstance().getPhotoCopyBitmap();
    //custom scalling is important to apply filter otherwise it will not apply on image
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmcopy, bitmcopy.getWidth()-1, bitmcopy.getHeight()-1, false);
    filter.processFilter(scaledBitmap);
    filterImage.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
}
```