# Immutable bitmap crash error

Tags: android, bitmap

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor
at android.graphics.Canvas.<init>(Canvas.java:127)
at app.test.canvas.StartActivity.applyFrame(StartActivity.java:214)
at app.test.canvas.StartActivity$1.onClick(StartActivity.java:163)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I get this crash error from the developer console .. I don't understand what is the problem ..

```
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    opt.inScaled = true;
    opt.inPurgeable = true;
    opt.inInputShareable = true;
    Bitmap brightBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), position, opt); 
    brightBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(brightBitmap, 550, 550, false);
    chosenFrame = brightBitmap;
    Bitmap workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(chosenFrame);
    workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(workingBitmap); 
    Canvas c = new Canvas(workingBitmap);
```

I think it's related to this ?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

You have to convert your `workingBitmap` to `Mutable Bitmap` for drawing on `Canvas`. (Note: this method does not help save memory, it will use extra memory)

```
Bitmap workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(chosenFrame);
Bitmap mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
```

This answer helps don't waste memory
[Convert immutable bitmap to a mutable bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9194259/925070)

Comment: this method helps save memory. I edited answer with simplest way to do mutable bitmap

Comment: when I use the method, then the app crashes and in the logcat it says that canvas can't use a recycled bitmap

Comment: So i use your method without the answer in the link ?

Comment: @dimetil How does it not waste memory? it actually creates a totally identical new bitmap so you use 2 times more memory on this bitmap ...

Comment: here's a method that saves memory, which i've created:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16314940/878126

Comment: what is chosenFrame ?

Answer (score 44):

`BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` returns an immutable copy of the bitmap and you cannot draw to its canvas. In order to get its canvas, you need to get a mutable copy of the images' bitmap and that can be done with single line code addition.

```
opt.inMutable = true;
```

Add that line to your code and it should address the crash.

Comment: this should be the answer since it doesnt consume memory which is the case when using bitmap.copy(...)

Comment: It' essential to check Bitmap properties and set them before loading Bitmap into memory. Use this answer if memory is an issue, esspecialy it is if you are using bitmap with big dimensions.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you don't want to make your IMMUTABLE bitmap to MUTABLE bitmap, you can save memory by  **ALWAYS REUSING THE BITMAP**

```
workingBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(workingBitmap);
```

However I think this may be same as making the bitmap mutable by calling

```
workingBitmap.isMutable = true
```

Comment: There is not variable called "isMutable" inside bitmap

Answer (score 5):

This works as well, I just tested it.

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inMutable = true;
return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(resultDecoded, 0, resultDecoded.length,options);
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to minimize memory usage, you can check out this post about converting/decoding a mutable bitmap straight from the resources :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16314940/878126