# Error with android camera code

Tags: java, android, camera

Whenever I run this code on my actual or virtual android device the program first opens up, to a screen with a button and an image view gadget and upon pressing of the button, it goes to the camera application and allows me to take a picture. The picture is saved, but after that the picture is supposed to open and a rectangle is supposed to be drawn but instead the program shuts off. It says "Stress Analysis has stopped working" could anyone please help me. I am new to android so a simple explanation would be appreciated.

### Main Activity

```
 package com.example.stressanalysis;

       import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
     import android.graphics.Bitmap;
     import android.graphics.Canvas;
      import android.graphics.Paint;
     import android.graphics.Rect;
      import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
ImageView imageView;
Button button1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    button1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        Rect r = new Rect(0,0,50,50); 
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(photo);
        canvas.drawRect(r, paint);

    }
}

    }
```

### Main Activity XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
    android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

### LogCat

```
    03-12 19:19:11.380: D/AndroidRuntime(11368): Shutting down VM
03-12 19:19:11.380: W/dalvikvm(11368): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4107e2a0)
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data dat=content://media/external/images/media/5291 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.stressanalysis/com.example.stressanalysis.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3179)
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3222)
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:140)
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1276)
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368):    at android.graphics.Canvas.<init>(Canvas.java:127)
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368):    at com.example.stressanalysis.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:42)
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5347)
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3175)
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368):    ... 11 more
03-12 19:19:20.755: I/Process(11368): Sending signal. PID: 11368 SIG: 9
```

### Console

```
    [2013-03-12 18:26:10 - StressAnalysis] ------------------------------
[2013-03-12 18:26:10 - StressAnalysis] Android Launch!
[2013-03-12 18:26:10 - StressAnalysis] adb is running normally.
[2013-03-12 18:26:10 - StressAnalysis] Performing com.example.stressanalysis.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-03-12 18:26:10 - StressAnalysis] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'AndroidTablet1'
[2013-03-12 18:26:10 - StressAnalysis] Uploading StressAnalysis.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-03-12 18:26:13 - StressAnalysis] Installing StressAnalysis.apk...
[2013-03-12 18:26:18 - StressAnalysis] Success!
[2013-03-12 18:26:18 - StressAnalysis] Starting activity com.example.stressanalysis.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2013-03-12 18:26:20 - StressAnalysis] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.stressanalysis/.MainActivity }
[2013-03-12 18:48:23 - StressAnalysis] ------------------------------
[2013-03-12 18:48:23 - StressAnalysis] Android Launch!
[2013-03-12 18:48:23 - StressAnalysis] adb is running normally.
[2013-03-12 18:48:23 - StressAnalysis] Performing com.example.stressanalysis.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-03-12 18:48:23 - StressAnalysis] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-03-12 18:48:33 - StressAnalysis] Uploading StressAnalysis.apk onto device 'c1607cb047e457f'
[2013-03-12 18:48:34 - StressAnalysis] Failed to install StressAnalysis.apk on device 'c1607cb047e457f': Local path doesn't exist.
[2013-03-12 18:48:34 - StressAnalysis] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Local path doesn't exist.
[2013-03-12 18:48:34 - StressAnalysis] Launch canceled!
[2013-03-12 18:48:38 - StressAnalysis] ------------------------------
[2013-03-12 18:48:38 - StressAnalysis] Android Launch!
[2013-03-12 18:48:38 - StressAnalysis] adb is running normally.
[2013-03-12 18:48:38 - StressAnalysis] Performing com.example.stressanalysis.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-03-12 18:48:38 - StressAnalysis] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-03-12 18:48:44 - StressAnalysis] Uploading StressAnalysis.apk onto device 'c1607cb047e457f'
[2013-03-12 18:48:44 - StressAnalysis] Installing StressAnalysis.apk...
[2013-03-12 18:48:47 - StressAnalysis] Success!
[2013-03-12 18:48:47 - StressAnalysis] Starting activity com.example.stressanalysis.MainActivity on device c1607cb047e457f
[2013-03-12 18:48:48 - StressAnalysis] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.stressanalysis/.MainActivity }
[2013-03-12 18:52:54 - AndroidTest] ------------------------------
[2013-03-12 18:52:54 - AndroidTest] Android Launch!
[2013-03-12 18:52:54 - AndroidTest] adb is running normally.
[2013-03-12 18:52:54 - AndroidTest] Performing com.example.androidtest.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-03-12 18:52:57 - AndroidTest] Uploading AndroidTest.apk onto device 'c1607cb047e457f'
[2013-03-12 18:52:57 - AndroidTest] Installing AndroidTest.apk...
[2013-03-12 18:52:59 - AndroidTest] Success!
[2013-03-12 18:52:59 - AndroidTest] Starting activity com.example.androidtest.MainActivity on device c1607cb047e457f
[2013-03-12 18:53:00 - AndroidTest] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.androidtest/.MainActivity }
[2013-03-12 19:15:36 - StressAnalysis] ------------------------------
[2013-03-12 19:15:36 - StressAnalysis] Android Launch!
[2013-03-12 19:15:36 - StressAnalysis] adb is running normally.
[2013-03-12 19:15:36 - StressAnalysis] Performing com.example.stressanalysis.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-03-12 19:15:36 - StressAnalysis] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-03-12 19:15:40 - StressAnalysis] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2013-03-12 19:15:40 - StressAnalysis] Starting activity com.example.stressanalysis.MainActivity on device c1607cb047e457f
[2013-03-12 19:15:41 - StressAnalysis] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.stressanalysis/.MainActivity }
[2013-03-12 19:15:41 - StressAnalysis] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this error in your log:

```
03-12 19:19:11.388: E/AndroidRuntime(11368): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result 
        ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=Intent { 
        act=inline-data dat=content://media/external/images/media/5291 (has extras) }}
        to activity {com.example.stressanalysis/com.example.stressanalysis.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor
```

Then, this answer might help:
[Immutable bitmap crash error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119582/android-immutable-bitmap-crash-error)