# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when rotating a bitmap

Tags: java, android, layout, bitmap

I'm trying to rotate a given bitmap by X degrees
in order to send it to my server rotated.

I'm using android API8

using this code:

```
  private static void rotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
 Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
 matrix.postRotate(angle);
 return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix,
  true);
  }
```

It works on Nexus 5, but on Galaxy Note2 I get the following error:

```
05-18 09:06:42.696: E/AndroidRuntime(6044): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-18 09:06:42.696: E/AndroidRuntime(6044):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
05-18 09:06:42.696: E/AndroidRuntime(6044):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:726)
05-18 09:06:42.696: E/AndroidRuntime(6044):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:703)
05-18 09:06:42.696: E/AndroidRuntime(6044):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:636)
```

Than I have read some posts in SOF

and changed to the following code:

```
  private static void rotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(source);
    Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix();
    matrix2.setRotate(angle, source.getWidth() / 2, source.getHeight() / 2);
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, matrix2, new Paint());
  }
```

but then I have gotten the following error:

`Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor`

**Update**

Then I have tried this code:

```
 private static void rotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
// Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
// matrix.postRotate(angle);
// return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix,
// true);

// Bitmap workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source);

Bitmap mutableBitmap = source.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
source.recycle();
// Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

// Canvas canvas = new Canvas(source);
Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix();
matrix2.setRotate(angle, mutableBitmap.getWidth() / 2, mutableBitmap.getHeight() / 2);
canvas.drawBitmap(mutableBitmap, matrix2, new Paint());
```

}

and got this error:

```
05-18 09:42:17.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18788): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-18 09:42:17.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18788):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCopy(Native Method)
05-18 09:42:17.906: E/AndroidRuntime(18788):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.copy(Bitmap.java:479)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: please post the complete Logcat

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119582/android-immutable-bitmap-crash-error

Comment: Is the problem hapening with all Bitmaps?

Comment: what do you need rotated Bitmap for? for saving on the sdcard? for drawing on the Canvas?

Comment: @pskink saving locally to send to my server.

Answer (score 0):

You are not recycling all bitmaps.
And after recycling you have to remove all the pointers linking to the bitmap.

Comment: Just set Bitmap variable equals to null.