# Jetpack Compose Immutable ImageBitmap to pass to Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-bitmap, android-jetpack-compose

Loading an immutable image to canvas crashes with

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor
```

both in classic Android Canvas and Compose Canvas.

Using the snippet below is the cause for crash in Jetpack Compose.

```
val deferredResource: DeferredResource<ImageBitmap> =
    loadImageResource(id = R.drawable.landscape2)

deferredResource.resource.resource?.let { imageBitmap ->
    val paint = Paint().apply {
        style = PaintingStyle.Stroke
        strokeWidth = 1f
        color = Color(0xffFFEE58)

    }
    Canvas(image = imageBitmap).drawRect(0f, 0f, 100f, 100f, paint)
}
```

Which is solved with Bitmap as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13119762/5457853) with

```
Bitmap workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(chosenFrame);
Bitmap mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
```

I can convert `ImageBitmap` to Android `Bitmap` using

```
        val bitmap = imageBitmap.asAndroidBitmap().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
```

Found that it's also possible to convert `Bitmap` back to `ImageBitmap` using

```
 val newImageBitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap()
```

And as result i get after drawing on that Bitmap with snippet below

```
  val canvas = Canvas(newImageBitmap)

    canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, 200f, 200f, paint = paint)
    canvas.drawCircle(
        Offset(
            newImageBitmap.width / 2 - 75f,
            newImageBitmap.height / 2 + 75f
        ), 150.0f, paint
    )

    Image(bitmap = newImageBitmap)
```

Is there a less convoluted way to draw on ImageBitmap with Canvas without converting back and forth between Bitmap and ImageBitmap?

Comment: Are you using correct `Canvas`? You should probably use `androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas` that has `onDraw` parameter.

Comment: I'm not using `androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas` for this one, using `fun Canvas(image: ImageBitmap): Canvas = ActualCanvas(image)`. The purpose here is to send Image as parameter, modify that Bitmap and return it with drawings on top of that bitmap. `drawImage` function  of  `androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas` draws an image only.

Answer (score 1):

`loadImageResource()` is using `AndroidImageBitmap` implementation with `Bitmap.decodeResource(resources, drawableId)` which requests calling it without options.

This is probably limitation of the compose. You'll probably need to write your own `loadingImageResource()` that will call your own `ImageBitmap` implementation with mutable `Bitmap`.

```kotlin
fun imageFromResource(res: Resources, resId: Int): ImageBitmap {
    return MutableAndroidImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, BitmapFactory.Options().apply { inMutable = true }))
}
```

```kotlin
class MutableAndroidImageBitmap(internal val bitmap: Bitmap) : ImageBitmap
```

Note that drawaing of this will fail since, conversion `asAndroidBitmap()` checks for implementation of `ImageBitmap` when drawing the `ImageBitmap` to the foundation `Canvas`.

I guess you should stick with the steps you have stated in the question. `asImageBitmap()` does not convert `ImageBitmap` to `Bitmap` it just return the wrapped internal property. Converting `Bitmap` to `ImageBitmap` does reading the of the pixel data and creates copy of it.

```
suspend fun ImageBitmap.mutate(context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext, config: Bitmap.Config) = withContext(context) {
    val workingBitmap = asAndroidBitmap() //this is just access to `bitmap` property
    val mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(config, true)
    workingBitmap.recycle()
    mutableBitmap.asImageBitmap()
}
```

Opened bug on issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177129056