# Changing the color of the pixel on touch

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

I am working to change the value of the image pixel which is touched by the user to green. I know these type of questions have already been answered but I am just having trouble in returning back or setting the returned pixel and reflecting that to the image.
I have taken the code from the following link:http://android-er.blogspot.ru/2012/10/get-touched-pixel-color-of-scaled.html
I changed the following to the code dont know if I am doing it correct.

```
int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

            int r = Color.red(touchedRGB);
            int b = Color.blue(touchedRGB);
            int g = Color.green(touchedRGB);


            r = 0;
            g = 255;
            b = 0;

            bitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(Color.alpha(touchedRGB), r, g, b));
```

Kindly please help me out with this small problem. Thanks

dot java file

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class webtest extends Activity {

    TextView touchedXY, invertedXY, imgSize, colorRGB;
    ImageView imgSource1, imgSource2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webtest);

        touchedXY = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xy);
        invertedXY = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.invertedxy);
        imgSize = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.size);
        colorRGB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.colorrgb);
        imgSource1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.source1);
        imgSource2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.source2);

        imgSource1.setOnTouchListener(imgSourceOnTouchListener);
        imgSource2.setOnTouchListener(imgSourceOnTouchListener);

    }

    OnTouchListener imgSourceOnTouchListener
            = new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();
            float[] eventXY = new float[] {eventX, eventY};

            Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
            ((ImageView)view).getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

            invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY);
            int x = Integer.valueOf((int)eventXY[0]);
            int y = Integer.valueOf((int)eventXY[1]);

            touchedXY.setText(
                    "touched position: "
                            + String.valueOf(eventX) + " / "
                            + String.valueOf(eventY));
            invertedXY.setText(
                    "touched position: "
                            + String.valueOf(x) + " / "
                            + String.valueOf(y));

            Drawable imgDrawable = ((ImageView)view).getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgDrawable).getBitmap();

            imgSize.setText(
                    "drawable size: "
                            + String.valueOf(bitmap.getWidth()) + " / "
                            + String.valueOf(bitmap.getHeight()));

            //Limit x, y range within bitmap
            if(x < 0){
                x = 0;
            }else if(x > bitmap.getWidth()-1){
                x = bitmap.getWidth()-1;
            }

            if(y < 0){
                y = 0;
            }else if(y > bitmap.getHeight()-1){
                y = bitmap.getHeight()-1;
            }

            int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

            int r = Color.red(touchedRGB);
            int b = Color.blue(touchedRGB);
            int g = Color.green(touchedRGB);


            r =0;
            g = 255;
            b = 0;

            bitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(Color.alpha(touchedRGB), r, g, b));



            colorRGB.setText("touched color: " + "#" + Integer.toHexString(touchedRGB));
            colorRGB.setTextColor(touchedRGB);

            return true;
        }};
```

xml layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/xy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="touched position: "/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/invertedxy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="inverted touched position: "/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/size"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="drawable size: "/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/colorrgb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="touched color: "/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/source1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/im1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/source2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/im5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is the logcat

```
 at android.graphics.Bitmap.setPixel(Bitmap.java:1425)
            at com.example.rohit2906.webtest.webtest$1.onTouch(webtest.java:96)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8382)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2739)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5791)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
03-25 22:18:43.235    1910-1910/com.example.rohit2906.webtest D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
03-25 22:18:43.236    1910-1910/com.example.rohit2906.webtest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rohit2906.webtest, PID: 1910
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.setPixel(Bitmap.java:1425)
            at com.example.rohit2906.webtest.webtest$1.onTouch(webtest.java:96)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8382)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2119)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2739)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3635)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3476)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5701)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5675)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5646)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5791)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Actually that answer includes to make the bitmap mutable but here even if my bitmap is not mutable I am asking if we have any other method to set my bitmap's Pixel to the changed color.
Here is the logcat of the code in answer.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.setPixel(Bitmap.java:1394)
            at com.example.rohit2906.webtest.webtest$1.onTouch(webtest.java:108)
            at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7706)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2068)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1515)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2458)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2016)
            at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7891)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3954)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3833)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3525)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3582)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3418)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3426)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3399)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5602)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5553)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5682)
            at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Looks OK to me.  Does it work?

Comment: no the app crashes. The app opens up but as soon as I touch it crashes.

Comment: Any kind of error message when that happens?

Comment: Let me add my complete code. look for the edit.

Comment: OK, I see your complete code.  But what about the error message in the logcat?  That will tell us what's going wrong.

Comment: My laptop hangs as soon as I run it on the emulator.Is there any other way to generate logcat.

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about the emulator that you're using.  My first thought would be to ask whether it comes with a debugger that will let you step through your code and see where it's actually failing.  But I'm quite sure that the code that you posted for turning a pixel green is correct.  So I wonder if you can tell me why you think that this is the code that's causing the problem?

Comment: I am using the exact code. it shows unfortunately the app stopped.I do have a debugger but dont know much about how to use it . Just now I tried to start the emulator and it crashed again.

Comment: You yourself can try the same code if everything is available with you and Kindly guide me with the same.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764839/error-with-setpixels

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an Android emulator on my laptop, and I'm not going to install one just to help you with this.  Have a look at the  link that @schlingel posted - I think it's very likely that your problem is a duplicate of this one.  In which case, Shlublu's answer is the one that you want.

Comment: Hey I havent still solved my problem help is appreciated thanks

Comment: Did you try Shlublu's answer from that other question?  Did anything change when you did?

Comment: Yes i have to make my butmap mutable .I did the same code as below but that too crashes the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code :

This code changes color of TextView. Modify it as per your requirement...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class webtest extends Activity {

    TextView touchedXY, invertedXY, imgSize, colorRGB;
    ImageView imgSource1, imgSource2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webtest);

        touchedXY = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xy);
        invertedXY = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.invertedxy);
        imgSize = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.size);
        colorRGB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.colorrgb);
        imgSource1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.source1);
        imgSource2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.source2);

        imgSource1.setOnTouchListener(imgSourceOnTouchListener);
        imgSource2.setOnTouchListener(imgSourceOnTouchListener);

    }

    OnTouchListener imgSourceOnTouchListener= new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();
            float[] eventXY = new float[] {eventX, eventY};

            Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
            ((ImageView)view).getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

            invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY);
            int x = Integer.valueOf((int)eventXY[0]);
            int y = Integer.valueOf((int)eventXY[1]);

            touchedXY.setText(
                    "touched position: "
                            + String.valueOf(eventX) + " / "
                            + String.valueOf(eventY));
            invertedXY.setText(
                    "touched position: "
                            + String.valueOf(x) + " / "
                            + String.valueOf(y));

            Drawable imgDrawable = ((ImageView)view).getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgDrawable).getBitmap();

            imgSize.setText(
                    "drawable size: "
                            + String.valueOf(bitmap.getWidth()) + " / "
                            + String.valueOf(bitmap.getHeight()));

            //Limit x, y range within bitmap
            if(x < 0){
                x = 0;
            }else if(x > bitmap.getWidth()-1){
                x = bitmap.getWidth()-1;
            }

            if(y < 0){
                y = 0;
            }else if(y > bitmap.getHeight()-1){
                y = bitmap.getHeight()-1;
            }

            //if(!bitmap.isRecycled())
            {
                int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

                int r = Color.red(touchedRGB);
                int b = Color.blue(touchedRGB);
                int g = Color.green(touchedRGB);


                r =0;
                g = 255;
                b = 0;

                Bitmap newbitmap = convertToMutable(bitmap);
                newbitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(Color.alpha(touchedRGB), r, g, b));

                colorRGB.setText("touched color: " + "#" + Integer.toHexString(touchedRGB));
                colorRGB.setTextColor(touchedRGB);
            }

            return true;
        }};


        public static Bitmap convertToMutable(Bitmap imgIn) {
            try {
                //this is the file going to use temporally to save the bytes. 
                // This file will not be a image, it will store the raw image data.
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temp.tmp");

                //Open an RandomAccessFile
                //Make sure you have added uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                //into AndroidManifest.xml file
                RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");

                // get the width and height of the source bitmap.
                int width = imgIn.getWidth();
                int height = imgIn.getHeight();
                Config type = imgIn.getConfig();

                //Copy the byte to the file
                //Assume source bitmap loaded using options.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_8888;
                FileChannel channel = randomAccessFile.getChannel();
                MappedByteBuffer map = channel.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, imgIn.getRowBytes()*height);
                imgIn.copyPixelsToBuffer(map);
                //recycle the source bitmap, this will be no longer used.
                //imgIn.recycle();
                System.gc();// try to force the bytes from the imgIn to be released

                //Create a new bitmap to load the bitmap again. Probably the memory will be available. 
                imgIn = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, type);
                map.position(0);
                //load it back from temporary 
                imgIn.copyPixelsFromBuffer(map);
                //close the temporary file and channel , then delete that also
                channel.close();
                randomAccessFile.close();

                // delete the temp file
                file.delete();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            return imgIn;
        }
}
```

Comment: I have already worked on this but I want to change the color of touched pixel. I can see you edited the code and I have done the same but it isnt working.

Comment: I think your answer is a good one but still the app crashes from the above code can u help me!